# Concerning the $\eta$-rule

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In Martin Lof's type theory, one has a term

$$
x:A, y:A, z: Id_A(x,y) \vdash J(r(x);x,y,z): Id_A(x,y)
$$

can one derive *judgemental* equality $J(r(x);x,y,z)=z$ without the $\eta$-rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $J(r(x);x, y, z)$ is in $\beta$-normal form. The only judgmental equality for $J$ is $\mathit{J}(pr;x, x, r(x)) = pr$ (using your notation) which does not apply here. If instead of judgmental equality, we consider $\mathit{Id}(J(r(x);x, y, z), z)$, that's provable by induction on $z$.